# Multiple Tailwind CSS Configs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, vite, inertiajs

I am building a project using Laravel/Inertia/Vue and I am using Tailwind CSS.
I want to have separate admin.css and client.css files using tailwindcss 3.2 ability to have multiple config files:

`./styles/admin.css`

```css
@config "./tailwind.admin.config.js"
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

but the problem is that Vite will build just app.css for me not the admin one

`vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    ssr: {
        noExternal: ['@inertiajs/server'],
    },
    server: {
        host: "localhost",
    },
});
```

app.css is imported in app.js

I can not figure it out
Could you please help me?

I want to have separate `admin.css` and `client.css` files per each tailwindcss config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of input files to vite as follows:

```
input: ['resources/js/app.js','resources/css/admin.css','resources/css/client.css']
```

This should result in seperate output files in your build directory.

If you want to keep the css as javascript import you can create a second InertiaApp for the admin area:

1. Copy app.js and rename it like 'admin.js'
2. Change css import in admin.js to '/styles/admin.css'
3. Change your vite input to: `input: ['resources/js/app.js','resources/js/admin.js']`
4. Use a different blade layouts for the 'admin' area with reference to admin.js instead of app.js : `@vite('resources/js/admin.js')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply it will now build two app css:
public/build/assets/app.ea99b5f4.css                           12.63 KiB / gzip: 3.09 KiB
public/build/assets/admin.ea99b5f4.css                         12.63 KiB / gzip: 3.09 KiB
public/build/assets/app.e0d75272.css

Comment: I need more proper structure i think. Its also recommended to refrence css files in js not directly to vite, thats another confusion for me,

Comment: welcome. For a better structure you could split your js, too.  Check my edit